# Combined MFA using 'TOTP' and 'Email' failing in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to enable combined MFA options for Azure B2C via custom policies but I'm receiving error while trying to do so. I've used https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone/policy/SignUpOrSignin_PhoneOrEmailMFA.xml as my starting point.

I'm getting error

```
Profile 'Jwt Issuer' in policy 'B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml' in tenant 'in group devb2c.xxxx.com' does not contain the required cryptographic key 'SamlAssertionSigning'
```

Please find below my custom policies for B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS.xml

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
  <Preconditions>
    <!--Sample: If the preferred MFA method is not 'phone' skip this orchestration step-->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
      <Value>totp</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <JourneyList>
    <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="TotpFactor-Input" />
  </JourneyList>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
  <Preconditions>
    <!--Sample: If the preferred MFA method is not 'phone' skip this orchestration step-->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
      <Value>email</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="Email-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

I've used https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone/policy/SignUpOrSignin_PhoneOrEmailMFA.xml as my starting point which is working as expected just tried to make changes on

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail">
  <DisplayName>Please select your preferred MFA method</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="TOTP " Value="totp" SelectByDefault="true" />
    <Enumeration Text="Email " Value="email" SelectByDefault="false" />   
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

I'm getting screen to enter my TOTP but in next step it fails with the message i.e. "Profile 'Jwt Issuer' in policy 'B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml' in tenant 'in group devb2c.xxxx.com' does not contain the required cryptographic key 'SamlAssertionSigning'"

Comment: What does your "Jwt Issuer" technical profile look like? It sounds like this isn't anything to do with MFA but that you're trying to issue a JWT in a SAML journey.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SAML authentication journey then you need to issue a SAML token at the end of it, not a JWT. The error is occurring because a JWT token issuer technical profile doesn't have the necessary elements to issue a SAML token.

**Don't add the SAML keys to the JWT issuer technnical profile.**

Instead, set up a [SAML token issuer technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-issuer-technical-profile), and use that as the last step of your SAML `UserJourney` instead of the `JwtIssuer` you already have:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Saml2AssertionIssuer">
  <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
  <OutputTokenFormat>SAML2</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IssuerUri">https://tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_SAML</Item>
    <Item Key="TokenNotBeforeSkewInSeconds">600</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="MetadataSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlIdpCert"/>
    <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlIdpCert"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims/>
  <OutputClaims/>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-issuer"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The Microsoft docs also have a full guide on how to [set up B2C to support SAML service providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) which may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this by adding `SamlAssertionSigning` and `SamlAssertionSigning` in the `Jwtissuer` Technical profile.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
  <DisplayName>JWT Issuer</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="None" />
  <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="client_id">{service:te}</Item>
    <Item Key="issuer_refresh_token_user_identity_claim_type">objectId</Item>
    <Item Key="SendTokenResponseBodyWithJsonNumbers">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    <Key Id="issuer_refresh_token_key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer" />
    <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlIdpCert" />
    <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlIdpCert" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims />
  <OutputClaims />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that worked to be honest and I wouldn't rely on that behaviour. JWTs and SAML tokens are fundamentally different, as is the process that generates them. If you have a SAML authentication journey then you should set up a [SAML token issuer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-issuer-technical-profile) and use that instead of a JWT token issuer.